# Magento 2 - I would like to understand the mechanism of running the "setup:di:compile" command

Tags: magento2, compiler, di

I would like to understand the mechanism of running the `setup:di:compile` command in Magento 2.

Example:

- Step 1: it is checking...
- Step 2: it is generating...
- ...

Anybody can explain it to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Overview of code compilation

Code compilation consists of all of the following in no particular order:

- Application code generation (factories, proxies, and so on)
- Area configuration aggregation (that is, optimized dependency
  injection configurations per area)
- Interceptor generation (that is, optimized code generation of
  interceptors)
- Interception cache generation
- Repositories code generation (that is, generated code for APIs)
- Service data attributes generation (that is, generated extension
  classes for data objects)

You can find code compilation in classes in the [\Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation) namespace.

For more information: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html

Hope it helps.